# What is the meaning of expression a = b != c;

Tags: c

I have the following code that I don't understand

```
shiftLeft = local.tasks.first != NULL;
if(!shiftLeft) 
  local.tasks.last = NULL;
```

I mean the shiftLeft variable (which is boolean) supposed to be evaluated last, so in the first place evaluates local.tasks.first != NULL, but what is that?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. That's pretty much the first thing you should've learned about C. Also, I think you forgot an `f` in one of your variables unless you're making a very raunchy game.

Comment: `!=` operator result has `int` type and may be `0` or `1`, so `shiftleft` becomes `0` or `1`.

Comment: @M.SChaudhari No, that question has absolutely nothing to do with this one.

Comment: Why is the `if` instruction indented differently than the first instruction ?

Comment: `shitLeft` lmfao.

Comment: @Serhio, I don't understand.. so shiftLeft becomes 1 if local.tasks.first is different than NULL?

Comment: @user1797147 Yes, exactly. Another comparison and logical operators (but not bitwise ones!) act in similar way. See chapter 6.5 of [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return either true or false value (depending on fact if `local.task.first` is a `NULL` value or not).

If `local.task.first` is `NULL` a `shiftLeft` variable will get `false` value,

If `local.task.first` is not a `NULL` value a `shiftLeft` variable will get `true` value.

What is important, we don't know type of `shiftLeft`, if it is a bool variable it will be "filled" with `true` or `false` value. If it is other kind of variable (for example an integer) it will be "filled" with 0 for `false` and with **something different than 0** for true (but we can't be sure what exactly).

Comment: Is boolean, I stated in first post.

Comment: But what I don't understand is this a short form of ternary such as shitLeft = local.tasks.first != NULL ? 0 :1;

Comment: @user1797147, Think of the expression as `a = (b != c);`, which is conceptually no different from `y = x + z`. The ternary operator `?` is not involved, but you're generally correct; it's logically equivalent to `a = b != c ? 1 : 0`, and so on.

Comment: Ok, thanks all, I didn't know that a != b can return something (unless you explicitely put in a IF condition), or if can be used to assign result of evaluation to another expression. Thanks!

Comment: I got'it now, thanks very much for your support. Comparing to ternary just because I very often need a short form and I didn't know that is possible in such way. Well, every day learning something new about C.. this is what I love at this lang :)

Comment: @user1797147 `!=` means "not equal". It's not part of the `if` statement, it's just generally an expression that's `true` if two things are equal and false otherwise. True and false are normal values in C like 13.4 or 'y'.

Comment: "...with something different than 0 for true (but we can't be sure what exactly)."  This is incorrect. No matter the type of the variable, it will get value 0 or 1. `false` and `true` as just macros defined to 0 and 1. This is guaranteed by the standard and we can be 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here `!=` expression is evaluated first because `!=` has higher precedence than `=`, so it first compares with `NULL` and then assign into  `shitLeft`.

If `shitLeft` is true then `if` condition is `false`, otherwise `if` condition `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The **b != c** part returns a boolean response (true or false). The result is then assigned to **a**.

In your example if local.tasks.first is not null then shitLeft (sic) is true. Otherwise it is false.